# Chrome - Detect "Account sign-in details are out of date"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When the underlying 2FA token is changed, Chrome shows this on the settings page:

[image]

Question: is there Javascript code or an API which will detect this state?  Note that calling `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo` will return the logged in user's email, just the same as if the sign-in details are *not* out of date.  So that API call can't be used to determine the out of date state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onSignInChanged event to get the state of the user signed into the browser.

You need "identity" in your manifest permissions in order for this to work.

```
chrome.identity.onSignInChanged.addListener(function(account, signedIn){
    console.log("AccountInfo", account);
    console.log("SignedInState", signedIn);
});
```

A chrome flag needs to be enabled also "Enable new profile management system" #enable-new-profile-management

The output of the above code when a user signs into a Chrome profile:

```
AcounntInfo -> Object
SignedInState true
```